# Setting a offset on my SQL Report with Paramters

Tags: reporting-services, bids

I'm using SQL reports for label printing and I want to be able to pass a top and left offset to the report to make float adjustments to where the data will appear on the label. I have all the data in a rectangle and I'm trying to using `TopOffset` and `LeftOffset` to move the rectangle from it's default position as needed. I can't find the proper expression to do this, or where to assign it.

I've tried going into the location properties of my offset rectangle and using these for my `Top` parameter:

```
=Parameters!TopOffset.Value + .14
=Parameters!TopOffset.Value in + .14 in
=(in)Parameters!TopOffset.Value + .14 in
```

I always get the error:

> =Parameters!TopOffset.Value + .14 in cannot be parsed as a unit because it does not contain numeric values. Examples of valid unit
>   strings are "1pt" and ".5in".

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't specify an expression for the location properties.

You would have to find another way to move the rectangle, by showing/hiding another item for example but it will be hard to do this as precisely as what you want.

Comment: Thank you. I had begun to suspect as much.